# In React, where are inline styles stored after render

Tags: css, reactjs

For example:
I have 2 components.
component 1 has inline styles.
component 2 uses styles from a CSS file.
Both components are on the screen at the same time in the same render.

Is the CSS that React generates from the inline styles stored in the same place in the DOM as the styles from the CSS file?

Are the styles generated by React removed from that location when the component with those inline styles is removed from the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say "inline styles", you mean this:

```
<span style={{ color: 'red' }}>Hello, World!</span>
```

In this case, the style isn't hoisted to css. It is rendered as part of the html. The result is:

```
<span style="color: red;">Hello, World!</span>
```

Comment: Thank You.  That's exactly what I was looking for.

Let me ask another question.  In your example above.  What are the advantages of the React's inline style vs. adding it to the HTML in the render function?

Comment: @Heath The first example above is "React's inline style", and when React executes the `render` function, that example will be written to the DOM as what you see in the second code snippet. So, in order to use `style={{ color: 'red' }}`, you would "add it to the HTML in the render function", and that is the same thing as "React's inline style". Does that clear things up?